# Проблемы дефолтной директории django

Tags: django, файлы

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static", # так не работает
    'C:/Users/uraya/PycharmProjects/web-app/djangosite/main/static', # а если вот так вручную тогда все ок
]
```

та же история с шаблонами, дефолтный путь не работает(

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'C:/Users/uraya/PycharmProjects/web-app/djangosite/main/templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

[image: вот все файлы проекта]

вот пример того если забрать путь который я сам прописал

```
'DIRS': [
                'C:/Users/uraya/PycharmProjects/web-app/djangosite/main/templates',
            ],
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит «не работает»?

Comment: если я не укажу путь вручную к папке templates и static, тогда как дефолтный путь указывает в то место где ваше нет такого файла

Comment: Вы не забыли прописать ваше приложение в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: нет...) Помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

для формирования относительных путей используй
`os.path.join`

для твоего случая `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

Comment: Да я просто забыли прописать приложение в INSTALLED_APPS, уже все окей, спасибо)